# How to translate this code from PyQt4 to PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm a complete novice programmer in PyGt. I have read the book about PyGt4 but now we have PyGt5 and I can not run my examples from book.

For example, this is the first example from the book (the easiest) You can see

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
```

but it's in the book

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

but I wrote PyQt5 because I have only PyQt5

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("The first program in PyQt")
window.resize(300, 70)
label = QtGui.QLabel("<center>Hello, world!</center>")
btnQuit = QtGui.QPushButton("&Close window")
vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(label)
vbox.addWidget(btnQuit)
window.setLayout(vbox)
QtCore.QObject.connect(btnQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), 
QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error:  AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'

**My attemp to find solution**:
I tried to run this code. Does not work. My program works but I can not close button "Close window"

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("The first example in PyQt")
window.resize(300, 70)

label = QLabel("<center>Hello, world!</center>")
btnQuit = QPushButton("&Close window")
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(label)
vbox.addWidget(btnQuit)
window.setLayout(vbox)

closed = pyqtSignal()
range_changed = pyqtSignal(int, int, name='rangeChanged')
valueChanged = pyqtSignal([int], ['QString'])

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: In general: check the documentation of (Py)Qt5 and search for the missing class. It might just be in another module.

Comment: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close your window you have to connect your button clicked signal to the close function of your window

```
btnQuit.clicked.connect(window.close)
```

The whole code would be :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("The first example in PyQt")
window.resize(300, 70)

label = QLabel("<center>Hello, world!</center>")
btnQuit = QPushButton("&Close window")
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(label)
vbox.addWidget(btnQuit)
window.setLayout(vbox)

btnQuit.clicked.connect(window.close)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Be careful for your unused imports, you should use

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

and replace `QApplication` by `QtWidgets.QApplication`, `QLabel` by `QtWidgets.QLabel` etc...

Keep in mind that signals have changed style since PyQt5 : [Description](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#old-style-signals-and-slots)